# WP REST - video and audio players

Tags: javascript, rest-api, videos, audio

I'm building a VUE JS based theme, and I'm using WP REST v2.
There is a problem - I can't make video and audio playlists work (built-in WP core feature). I already added:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-mediaelement' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-playlist' );
```

but from there I'm not sure how to make it work.

I just can't make it work. When I insert content from the REST API into DOM the video and and music playlists are not working.

I have access to `WPPlaylistView` so I also tried:

`jQuery(".wp-playlist:not(:has(.mejs-container))").each(function() { return new WPPlaylistView({ el: this }); });`

But I'm still getting the error : "**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined**"

Does somebody know how to deal with this problem?
How can I make these WordPress playlists work when the player code is added to the DOM after the page loads?

Comment: IMHO you will have to find out yourself and teach us ;)

Comment: I will say as Mark Kaplun but in another form : what is the question ?

Comment: 3 1/2 years later and I didn't find much info about this anywhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ran into this same issue and I found the answer after many hours and almost giving up. It's in a bit of code that written to make the Customizer work with playlists. Checkout this comment from `/wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-text.php`:

```
    /**
     * Enqueue preview scripts.
     *
     * These scripts normally are enqueued just-in-time when a playlist shortcode is used.
     * However, in the customizer, a playlist shortcode may be used in a text widget and
     * dynamically added via selective refresh, so it is important to unconditionally enqueue them.
     *
     * @since 4.9.3
     */
    public function enqueue_preview_scripts() {
        require_once dirname( __DIR__ ) . '/media.php';

        wp_playlist_scripts( 'audio' );
        wp_playlist_scripts( 'video' );
    }
```

So this is being used in the customizer, which also loads the HTML dynamically after the page has loaded. If we want to do a similar thing on the front end, we will also need to definitely load these things when the page first loads. Here's the code I ended up using:

```
function squarecandy_wp_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-playlist' );
    require_once get_home_path() . 'wp-includes/media.php';
    wp_playlist_scripts( 'audio' );
    wp_playlist_scripts( 'video' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'squarecandy_wp_enqueue_scripts' );
```

Boom! Now you can run `wp.playlist.initialize()` in your js at anytime without errors.

One more thing to note: This issue can be particularly vexing to troubleshoot because if you have a page that naturally contains a playlist on the initial page load, then you can load additional playlist HTML on to the page and then run `wp.playlist.initialize()` and everything works out fine. It only fails if you have no playlists on your initial page (so this mysterious "just-in-time" enqueue never happens) and then you try and load in a playlist later.

### Update

This works better, now that we don't need to support IE9 anymore:

```php
function squarecandy_wp_enqueue_scripts() {
    if ( defined( 'ABSPATH' ) && ! is_admin() && ! wp_doing_ajax() ) {
        require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/media.php';
        wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-playlist' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-mediaelement' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-mediaelement' );
        add_action( 'wp_footer', 'wp_underscore_playlist_templates', 0 );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'squarecandy_wp_enqueue_scripts' );
```